# Is $\ell^1$ a Banach space which is uncountably infinite dimensional?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

We know that $ℓ^1=\left\{(x_n)_n :\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty |x_n|<\infty \right\}$ with the usual norm $$||(x_n)_n||=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty |x_n|$$ is a $\bf Banach$ space which is infinite dimensional.

We can easily check that the set $\{e_n\}_0^\infty$ such that: $$e_n=(0,0,\cdots,0,\underbrace{1}_{n^{th}},0,\cdots)$$ is a set of linearly independent vectors in $ℓ^1$.

But there is a theorem saying that if a $V$ is a Banach space then either $V$ is finite dimensional or $\bf uncountably$ infinite dimensional.

But we see that the set $\{e_n\}_0^\infty$ is countable.

What I did not understand?

Comment: $e_n$ is not an "algebraic" or Hamel basis of the space, meaning not every vector is a _finite_ linear combination of the vectors $e_n$. Any Hamel basis of an infinite dimensional Banach space has to be uncountable.

Comment: $\{e_1\}$ is also a set of linearly independent vectors in $\ell^1$.  Does that mean $\ell^1$ is $1$-dimensional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $B  = \{e_n\}$ is linearly independent, but not a basis of the vector space $\ell^1$. In fact, the set of all linear combinations of elements of $B$ is 
$$\ell_0 = \{ (x_n) \mid x_n = 0 \text{ for all but finitely many } n \} .$$

Comment: thanks, your answer is clear, can you give me an example of a sequence wich is not a combination of the set B

Comment: Take $x_n = 1/n^2$. Then $x_n \ne 0$ for all $n$ and $\sum \lvert x_n \rvert = \pi/6$.